# Coloured underlines on links without underlining image with links

Tags: html, css, underline

Can anyone give me a hand trying to add a different coloured line (to the the text)under a link without using the `border-bottom: 1px #fff;` technique?

Currently, When I use this technique, it is also putting a line under any graphic with a link on it.

Comment: why not add an extra class in the image link?

Comment: The only way to do is to use border, and you must be using a general element selector like `a {border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;}` so don't do that, use a `class` or `nested` selector instead

Comment: Can you not turn off the border for image links? a img {border: 0;}

Comment: @user2910731: can you add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

Style :

```
article {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: green;
}
span.red_text {
      color:red;
}
```

Html:

```
<article>      
    <span class="red_text">The text color is red!</span>      
</article>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Pc2Y/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

this could help you. using css, you can customize underline of links
http://alistapart.com/article/customunderlines

Answer (score 0):

You told you dont want to use `border-bottom: 1px #fff;`

So please you can use `box-shadow inset` and set the value

```
box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px red inset;
```

Answer (score -3):

If you get a line under any graphic with a link on it, are you giving the style like,
`a {border-bottom: 1px #fff;}` ?
Instead create a class and apply it to only to links where you need the custom underline like,

```
.customUnderline {border-bottom: 1px #fff solid;}

<a class="customUnderline">Your link</a>
```

Comment: the Questioner Clearly mentioned dont want Border-bottom. So this answer is not helpful

Comment: The Questioner didn't want to use the border-bottom technique as, by default, it also applied to images.